# How to convert a Complete Binary Tree to a Priority Search Tree in O(n)?

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, search-trees

I would like to know if there is a linear-time algorithm ($\mathcal{O(n)}$ time) to convert a
Complete Binary Tree with data left-to-right increasing stored in
external nodes, to a [Priority Search
Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_search_tree).

By conversion, my aim is to create a "Priority Search Tree" with all of the elements of some "Complete Binary Tree", or to modify the original "Complete Binary Tree" such that it has all of the properties of a "Priority Search Tree".

Comment: What's a priority search tree?  What relationship do you want the priority search tree to have to the complete binary tree?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @D.W. from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_search_tree,  a priority search tree is a tree data structure for storing points in two dimensions. It is effectively an extension of the priority queue with the purpose of improving the search time from O(n) to O(s + log n) time, where n is the number of points in the tree and s is the number of points returned by the search

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Could you [edit] your question to specify what relationship you want the  priority search tree to have to the complete binary tree?   Also, please tell us your thoughts.  What is the best algorithm you've found so far for doing the conversion, and what is its running time?

Comment: I have not been able to find a best algorithm as I have found no resources on any conversion algorithm.

Comment: I suggest you think about the problem yourself.  Don't just assume you'll find it somewhere else and give up if you can't find it elsewhere; try to find an algorithm yourself and show us what progress you've made.  Also, please [edit] the question to provide the information I requested.  It's not clear what you mean by "convert", so I don't think the question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: Please don't use "stuff.  edit: more stuff".  Instead, revise your question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you could, you'd obtain a sorting algorithm that would run in $O(n)$ time (construct the priority search tree, then traverse the nodes in increasing order of key), but you can't sort in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: edited the original question. What if I were to modify the original tree such that it became a valid priority search tree? Would that be possible?

Comment: @EpicNicks, I don't want to answer a question that is changing after it is answered.  Please make sure that you know what question you want to ask before you post it.  If you have a follow-up question, I suggest asking it separately with the 'Ask Question' button.  As far as your question, try thinking about it yourself!  Does the argument I gave apply to your follow-up question too?  Why or why not?  Be resourceful!  I believe you can figure it out.

Comment: I apologize for the change. It was just I did not have a concrete way to start the solution. The reason I left it vague to start was to see if there was some potentially overlooked creative solution that might have been done by someone using these forums. I figured given the initial complete binary tree, changing the original was within the constraints of the initial question. I had further modified it to avoid confusion after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm with amortized time of O(n) is possible. The algorithm below runs bottom-up and the average case running time is O(n) [visiting each node in the tree once] with fixes on broken child nodes running only on external nodes. The Algorithm has a worst-case time complexity of nlog*n as the worst-case child node fix will run through at most one branch of the tree starting on its third rank, with subsequent fixes taking one branch of the previous tree starting on its third rank iteratively (hence log*n).

Here is an implementation in python.

```
def bubble(node):
    # base case: leaf node
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        data = node.data
        return data
    else:
        leftData, rightData = None, None
        if node.left is not None:
            if node.left.data is not None:
                leftData = node.left.data
            else:
                leftData = bubble(node.left)
        if node.right is not None:
            if node.right.data is not None:
                rightData = node.right.data
            else:
                rightData = bubble(node.right)
        if leftData is None:
            node.data = rightData
            node.right = None
        elif rightData is None:
            node.data = leftData
            node.left = None
        else:
            if leftData > rightData:
                node.data = leftData
                node.left.data = None
                data = bubble(node.left)
                if data is None:
                    node.left = None
            else:
                node.data = rightData
                node.right.data = None
                data = bubble(node.right)
                if data is None:
                    node.right = None
        return node.data
```

Answer (score 0):

By a reduction form sorting problem to your problem, in polynomial time, we can find a lower bound for your problem.

Suppose you want to sort $n$ numbers, then set the priority of all numbers be an equal value, so we reduce Sorting problem to your problem, hence the problem at least hard as  [Sorting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), therefore we can't solve your problem in $o(n\log n)$ because the lower bound of Sorting problem is $\Omega(n\log n)$.